Load video by chunks using angular and net core
Angular(@videogular/ngx-videogular) and .net core
I am trying to load a big video by chunks using angular and .net core.
I want to be able to load the first chunk, to be able to play it, to load the next chunks and to append it to the video src without stopping the video.
In Angular, I was trying using MediaSource, but some videos I do not know the codecs, and at the second append the source closes and the chunk is not added.
.net core code:
var range = Request.Headers["Range"].ToString();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(range))
{
    return BadRequest("Range header is required");
}

var (start, end) = ParseRange(range, videoSize);

if (start >= videoSize)
{
    // Requested range is beyond the end of the file
    return StatusCode(416); // Range Not Satisfiable
}

var chunkLength = Math.Min(end - start + 1, videoSize - start); // Adjust chunk length if end exceeds file size

Response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", $"bytes {start}-{start + chunkLength - 1}/{videoSize}");
Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", chunkLength.ToString());
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
var contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = "video.mp4",
    Inline = false 
};
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());

var videoStream = new FileStream(_videoPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
videoStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var buffer = new byte[chunkLength];
videoStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)chunkLength);

return File(buffer, "video/mp4");

private (long, long) ParseRange(string rangeheader, long videosize)
{
  var range = rangeheader.Replace("bytes=", "").Split('-');
  var start = range[0] == "" ? 0 : long.Parse(range[0]);
  var end = range[1] == "" ? videosize - 1 : long.Parse(range[1]);

     // ensure end position does not exceed file size
  end = Math.Min(end, videosize - 1);

  return (start, end);
}

Angular:
@ViewChild('video') video: ElementRef<HTMLVideoElement>;
baseUrl = 'YOUR_API_BASE_URL'; // Replace with your API base URL
chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB
startRange = 0;
endRange = this.chunkSize - 1;
isEndOfStreamRequested = false;
sourceBuffer: SourceBuffer;
mediaSource = new MediaSource();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.video.nativeElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.mediaSource);
  this.mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => this.onSourceOpen());
}

getVideoChunk(start: number, end: number, url: string): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Range': `bytes=${start}-${end}` });
  return this.http.get(url, { headers, responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
}

async onSourceOpen() {
  try {
    this.sourceBuffer = this.mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
    this.sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', () => this.onUpdateEnd());
    this.fetchAndAppendChunk();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error adding source buffer:', error);
  }
}

fetchAndAppendChunk() {
  if (this.isEndOfStreamRequested) return;

  const url = `${this.baseUrl}/api/videos/video.mp4`;
  this.getVideoChunk(this.startRange, this.endRange, url).subscribe({
    next: (data: ArrayBuffer) => {
      this.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data);
      this.startRange = this.endRange + 1;
      this.endRange += this.chunkSize;
    },
    error: (error) => {
      if (error.status === 416) {
        this.isEndOfStreamRequested = true;
        this.mediaSource.endOfStream();
      } else {
        console.error('Error fetching chunk:', error);
      }
    }
  });
}

onUpdateEnd() {
  if (!this.isEndOfStreamRequested) {
    this.fetchAndAppendChunk();
  }
}
}

Also, i was trying to load the full video, but is taking too much, and it's creating the Blob file which can be downloaded.
Another option, i was trying was:
fetchNextChunk() {
  this.libraryService.getVideoChunk(this.startRange, this.endRange, api/library/${video}/videos/${this.videoName})
    .subscribe({
      next: (data: Blob) => {
        this.chunks.push(data);
        this.startRange = this.endRange + 1;
        this.endRange `your text`+=  this.chunkSize;
        // here i want to add the chunk to video src
        this.fetchNextChunk();

        },
      error: (error) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 416) {
          this.updateVideoSource();
        }
      }  
  });
}

updateVideoSource() {
  const videoElement = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
  const concatenatedChunks = new Blob(this.chunks, { type: 'video/mp4' });

  this.objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(concatenatedChunks);
  videoElement.src = this.objectURL;
}

but, still cannot add the chunk at video's src and then add the chunks progresively.
